# Vim NERD Commenter \c deletes the line instead of toggling comments

Tags: vim, nerdcommenter

The following works fine for me, it will comment out the current line:

```
<Leader>cc
```

but according to the docs (https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter#usage) if I want to toggle comments I do:

```
<Leader>c
```

which deletes the current line for me.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This command is actually `<Leader>c<space>`, not just `<Leader>c` (see [this issue](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/issues/109); this is not properly displayed in the readme).

Comment: Thanks that wasn't obvious to me!

Answer (score 0):

mac

```
map <C-_> <plug>NERDCommenterToggle<CR>
imap <C-_> <Esc><plug>NERDCommenterToggle<CR>i
```

windows

```
" Alt-/ to toggle comments
  map <A-/> <plug>NERDCommenterToggle<CR>
  imap <A-/> <Esc><plug>NERDCommenterToggle<CR>i
```